# Angularjs datepicker ng-model format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ngmodel

I have the following piece of code that displays an  input area and a datepicker popup

```
<input close-on-date-selection="false" type="text"
       id="startDate" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"
       ng-model="myCtryl.startDate"
       max-date="myCtrl.maxDate"
       datepicker-options="myCtrl.dateOptions"
       ng-change="myCtrl.validateDate()"/>
```

The date model is bound to `startDate` variable. My problem is, initially this `startDate` variable is in string format. When I debug `startDate` variable at the opening of the page, it looks like:

[image]

Whenever I make a selection on the datepicker, this variable turns into date format. Following is the screenshot of the variable after I select a date from the datepicker:

[image]

Here are the related parts of the controller. Initially I show today's date on the input area of the datepicker:

```
vm.todayDt = new Date();
vm.todayDt = $filter('date')(vm.todayDt, 'dd.MM.yyyy');
vm.startDate = vm.todayDt;
```

Here, the filter might be the problem. I tried removing that line too. When I removed that line, startDate became a date object at initial state too, but this time it shows "28.20.1614" on the input of the datepicker:

[image]

even though the dateobject is correct when I debug the variable:

[image]

What can I do to make the date object and the input area consistent? I.e., the object should be always in date format and it should show correctly on the input area. Thanks.

Comment: `vm.startDate = mv.todayDt;` should be `vm.startDate = vm.todayDt;`? Is that just a typo in the example?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo, corrected.